# JQM Toggle flip switch error calling refresh

Tags: user-interface, slidetoggle, jquery-mobile

i am new to JQM.
I am trying to set up a switch control for home automation. There are switches for every room to be controlled by phone or computer.
THe issue I am having is that I have one toggle flip switch which should switch the whole group on or off. The problem is the updating of the other toggle flip switches on the side, eg. when selecting 'off' for the whole group all switches should be changed to 'off' or vice versa for the 'on' option. if any of the other switches is selected the 'Whole Group' switch should not be changed.
I have tried all kinds of refresh options but either the page hangs completely or I get the following error

Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'.

I have tried all different answers given in the forum, but none is working on Chrome, Firefox or iPhone Safari.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(".tswitch").bind("change", function (event, ui) {
    var n = $(this).val();
    console.log('Start value n: ' + n);
    if (n == '0') {

        $('.tswitch').val('1');
        $('.tswitch').slider("refresh");
        <!--$('.tswitch').val('1').trigger('create').slider("refresh")-->

        console.log('0 toggle: ' + $(this).val() + ' value n: ' + n);
    } else {
        $('.tswitch').val('0');
        $('.tswitch').slider("refresh");
        <!--$('.tswitch').val('1').trigger('create').slider("refresh")-->

        <!--var fts = $('.tswitch');-->
        <!--fts.val('0');-->
        <!--fts.trigger('create');-->
        <!--fts.slider('refresh');-->

        console.log('1 toggle: ' + $(this).val() + ' value n: ' + n);
    }
});
```

});

the code is on http://jsfiddle.net/PdkQ5/98/

also tried JQM 1.8 and 2.0